# PyCharm unable to connect to GhostDriver

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, pycharm

I have a unit test that is passing when I run it via `python manage.py test`, but failing when I run it from within PyCharm.

```
def test_alpha(self):
    from selenium.webdriver.common.utils import free_port
    from selenium import webdriver

    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=PHANTOMJS_PATH, port=free_port())
    driver.quit()
```

The exception I get when running from PyCharm is

```
WebDriverException: Message: 'Can not connect to GhostDriver'
```

I've spent a fair amount of time digging into this problem, and I've noticed that when I specify a port manually the test passes within PyCharm.

```
# suppose 50000 happens to be a free port on your computer
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=PHANTOMJS_PATH, port=50000)
```

To quickly recap:

- Test passes with `python manage.py test`
- Test passes in PyCharm if port is specified manually
- Test fails in PyCharm if `port=free_port()`

What is PyCharm doing that is making the test unable to connect to Ghostdriver?

---

```
# For convenience, the `free_port()` code snippet is here
# selenium.webdriver.common.utils.freeport

def free_port():
    free_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    free_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 0))
    free_socket.listen(5)
    port = free_socket.getsockname()[1]
    free_socket.close()
    return port
```

Comment: What does `free_port()` return in PyCharm? What OS do you use?

Comment: I use OS X - and free_port() usually returns a port between 50000-60000.

Comment: Does it help if you start PyCharm from the Terminal: `open -a /Applications/PyCharm.app/`?

Comment: @CrazyCoder YES IT DOES! The test passes when I open PyCharm from the terminal. Thank you!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/135688/104891. Something in your terminal environment affects the networking.

Answer (score 1):

Something in your terminal setup probably influences the networking.

Try to **start PyCharm from your terminal**:

```sh
open -a /Applications/PyCharm.app/
```

Then run the test again, and it should pass.

---

*Source: sum-up of @CrazyCoder's comments*

Answer (score 0):

Try installing phantomjs with npm: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs.
I use Mac OS X and I had a similar issue using by selenium and django.