# Python: Selenium unable to find a free port on UDOO

Tags: python, sockets, selenium, debian

I'm just starting to play with UDOO (a single board computer similar to Raspberry Pi). I have some code that I'm trying to get some test code working on it without any luck.

The following code works on my Ubuntu laptop.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import timeit


def test():
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
    import time

    display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
    display.start()

    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get('http://www.google.com')
    q = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
    q.send_keys("python")
    q.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    time.sleep(4)

    results = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('g')
    for result in results:
        try:
            print '-' * 80
            print result.text
        except:
            pass

    browser.close()
    display.stop()
    return 0

print(timeit.timeit("test()", setup="from __main__ import test", number=10))
```

However when I run the same file on the UDOO board, it get the following error message:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./selenium_test.py", line 36, in <module>
    test()
  File "./selenium_test.py", line 16, in test
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 41, in __init__
    PORT = utils.free_port()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/utils.py", line 27, in free_port
    free_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 0))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

I did some testing on my laptop and under normal conditions, free_port() will return an open port on the system very quickly. When I execute the same tests on the UDOO board, it crashes every time.

This is a similar problem as this post ([PyCharm unable to connect to GhostDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827448/pycharm-unable-to-connect-to-ghostdriver)) which ended up being an environment variable issue within PyCharm. Unfortunately the solution in that post doesn't apply to this situation because I'm executing the script from the command line.

**Laptop (successful environment):** Dell Latitude E6520, Ubuntu 12.04, Intel Core i5

**Development Board (unsuccessful environment):** UDOO Quad, Debian 7 (wheezy), ARM Processor

Any ideas? Do you need any additional information to help diagnose the problem?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I continued playing around after posting this question. It turns out that I couldn't ping 127.0.0.1 either so I looked into my loopback device.

I added:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

to /etc/network/interfaces and ran:

```
sudo ifup lo
```

to initialize my loopback device. It runs great now.